# Threshold for auto encoder anomaly detection

Tags: anomaly-detection, autoencoder

I have fitted an auto encoder on 25-dimensional time series data hoping to be able to detect anomalies. training set is 100k observations, testset for threshold setting is 10k observations. all observations are 1 minute apart.
In the plot below the threshold is defined as the .9999 quantile of MAE across the 25-variables in a seperate test. Ideally we would want the threshold to be crossed in april and midseptember. We larger errors both places compared to the errors in the period before. But from the plot it seems that seasonality has an impact on the size of the errors and according to the fixed threshold everything from may till october is an anomaly.
[image]
Would it make sense to make some kind of varying threshold that adapts to a gradual increase in error size but detects spikes like the one seen in september?

Comment: What window length are you using for the autoencoder?

Comment: Do you have a single time-series with 100k time-steps, or 100k time-series such as the one shown?

Comment: How is "anomaly" defined for your problem?